# Deleting entries SharedPreferences in android

Tags: android

Hi
I have want delete all the entries in my SharedPreferences in android.How can I accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()`. [Documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear%28%29)